# initialising a variable with array variables in shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, variables

I am trying to concatenate strings using array variable but getting error.

```
declare -a arr
arr=(one two three)
var= "${arr[0]}    ${arr[1]}"
echo $var
```

expected output

```
one    two
```

(4 spaces between one and two)

I am getting following error:-

```
[wasadmin@gblabvl31 IBM]$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 10: one     two: command not found
```

Does this mean we can't assign a variable with array element (used as a variable)?
What is the other way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove the space after the `=`:

```
var="${arr[0]}    ${arr[1]}"
```

Bash supports a syntax that allows you to temporarily set a variable when you call a command. The syntax works like that `VARNAME=somevalue command`. This will execute the command, having set the (environment) variable `VARNAME` to `somevalue`. If you say `VARNAME= command` then bash interprets that as `VARNAME="" command` i.e. sets the variable to the empty string. In your case, that causes bash to try to execute the `"${arr[0]}    ${arr[1]}"` part as if it was a command.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra space in the assignment. Replace

```
var= "${arr[0]}    ${arr[1]}"
#   ^
```

with

```
var="${arr[0]}    ${arr[1]}"
```

You should also quote the argument of echo to preserve the whitespace in it

```
echo "$var"
```

The reason for the error message you see, is that when there is a space after the equal sign, bash interprets the command as assigning an empty environment variable named `var`, and then tries to execute the command `"${arr[0]}    ${arr[1]}"` which is evaluated to `one     two`, and thus the  command not found error